# Drupal 9/10: How to create Event Location + Events using CiviCRM Entity

Tags: civievent, civicrm-entity, drupal-9

I have enabled the CiviCRM Entity module. How can we create an event location and event in CiviCRM using a single form submission?

This functionality was achievable in Drupal 7 using https://skvare.com/blog/civicrm-entity-and-drupal-integration-whats-new-whats-next.

Is there a way to achieve the same in Drupal 8/9/10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems doable using https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form.

Steps I followed was:

- Enable `Location Block`, `Address` & `Event` Entities in CiviCRM Entity Settings page.
- Ensure module weight for CiviCRM Entity is lower than `Inline entity form`.

```
drush ev 'module_set_weight("civicrm_entity", -10);'
```

- Rebuild cache (`drush cr`) 2-3 times before proceeding for the next step.
- Structure => CiviCRM Entity => CiviCRM Location block => Manage Form Display
- Enable Address ID field and ensure Widget is set to `Inline entity form`.
  [image]
- Similarly, enable Location Block ID field and set the widget to `Inline entity form` in Structure => CiviCRM Entity => CiviCRM Event => Manage Form Display
- Visit the form at `/civicrm-event/add` to create events

Note: APIv3 requires contact_id and location_type_id field while creating address in civicrm. The former is not required while creating address for events so can be considered as an api bug.

Ensure these 2 fields are present on the Address entity to avoid any fatal error on the form submission.

[image]